# Unable to find node in xmlRoot Google RSS feed in R

Tags: xml, r, web, rss, screen-scraping

I want to scrape the news articles in my Google alerts RSS feed. This is my code in R using the XML package:

```
install.packages("XML") 
library(XML)

doc1<xmlTreeParse("http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/15985631956668437618/934829089626358614") 
file<-xmlRoot(doc1)
src<-xpathApply(file[5]$entry,"\\entry")
```

This is what I think the problem is:

1. The xmlRoot() function creates a list of 24 elements. If there was only 1 element, the xpathApply() function will be able to detect the nodes, as in this example here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-build-a-dataset-in-r-using-an-rss-feed-or-web-page/
2. The urls for the news articles that I am looking for are hidden in a mess of html code.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me with this issue, or give alternative approaches to the problem. Thank you.

Comment: So what's the desired output?

Comment: @MrFlick The desired output is a dataframe of all scraped newspaper articles from the RSS feed.

Comment: What specifically are the values form this example you want to extract. I don't know what "all the scraped newspaper articles" are. Is your problem just that you're using an invalid XPATH expression (it should be ""//entry" not "\\entry"). Your `file` object is an XMLNode and can handle an `xpathApply()` no problem. Maybe you should share your exact error.

Comment: @MrFlick You're right, it should be forward slashes, thanks!

My main issue is when I run
file<-xmlRoot(doc1)
src<-xpathApply(file[5]$entry,"//entry/link")

I get the following:

[[1]]
<link href="https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&amp;sa=t&amp;url=http://news.yahoo.com/gas-prices-economy-experts-disagree-drives-u-demand-040959681--business.html&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyHTUzZWZhNjQxYzUyZmJhYmY6Y29tLnNnOmVuOlNH&amp;usg=AFQjCNGVMe4hX4m9pNrwT0d_0XHMn8rNZg"/>

Comment: @Mr Flick When what I want is the content of the article from the URL
 
"news.yahoo.com/gas-prices-economy-experts-disagree-drives-u-demand-040959681--business.html&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyHTUzZWZhNjQxYzUyZmJhYmY6Y29tLnNnOmVuOlNH&amp;usg=AFQjCNGVMe4hX4m9pNrwT0d_0XHMn8rNZg"

Comment: @MrFlick I am now able to extract the URLs that I need, now the main problem would be extracting the content from each of these URLs. That would be a question for a separate page. Thank you for your help.

library(RCurl)
library(XML)
script <- getURL("http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/15985631956668437618/934829089626358614")
doc <- htmlParse(script)
li <- getNodeSet(doc, "//entry//link")
urls <- sapply(li, xmlGetAttr, "href")